# How to make a "reduction" from an arpeggiated bass

Tags: analysis, voice-leading

[image: Example 7.5 from "Harmonic Practice" by Robert Gauldin: Bach Cello Suite No. 4, Bourée, m. 11]

In one of my textbooks (*Harmonic Practice* by Robert Gauldin), there is a section about figuration and making reductions from arpeggiations to better see the voice leading. In the provided example the bassline is reduced to quarter note two voice texture but in my own reduction I came up with this:

[image: four-voice reduction]

I don't understand why their reduction uses 2 note texture in quarter notes. Can someone tell me why my reduction is incorrect and the books is correct or is this just an interpretation? Wouldnt it make sense from an analyses perspective to use my reduction since it clearly shows the chords being used?

Comment: I'm not sure how you got a time signature of 4/4 out of ¢ (i.e. 2/2)

Comment: It is just in my DAW that I didnt set it correctly, please forgive me

Comment: Don't worry, it shouldn't make any any difference to the analysis, I just thought it was a bit funny

Answer (score 2):

The critical factor is that they're expressing the voice leading, not the harmonic progression. The issue is less that the reduction uses quarter notes versus half notes and more that the book is expressing a two-voice texture, whereas the alternative reduction expresses a three-and-four-voice texture.

The book reduction interprets each pair of arpeggiated notes as upper and lower voices. Thinking in terms of Bb major, where the passage cadences, the lower voice moves in a very standard 1-6-4-5-1 pattern (much like a bass voice in a root position I-vi-IV-V-I progression) and the upper voice moves in an equally standard descending thirds pattern of 3-1-2-7-1.

The alternative interpretation is also problematic because it suggests a 4-2 chord resolving to a root position chord, which would be generally incorrect. 4-2 chords should usually resolve to 6 chords so that the chordal seventh is properly resolved.

Comment: Aaron, I dont understand why two voice texture shows the voice leading better than a 4 voice texture? When we study voice leading we do it using 4 voices so how does this reduction show the voice leading better just by using 2 voices?

Comment: @armani The 4-2 chord in your reduction resolves incorrectly. Your reduction also doesn't expose the 1-6-4-5-1 and 3-1-2-7-1 melodic patterns. Just because you study voice leading in a 4-voice context doesn't mean there are always four voices.

Comment: Yes you are right about the 42 chord. If I changed the last chord would my reduction be valid and show the voice leading correctly?

Comment: @armani It's not that your reduction is invalid; it just doesn't express what the book's does. No, changing the last chord wouldn't help. The Eb in the previous chord should resolve to D, and that D should be the lowest pitch in the chord. The chord doesn't have a D in it to begin with. And your reduction still wouldn't reveal the melodic contour, which is the whole point of voice-leading.

Comment: Ok, I need to think about this some more I guess. Thanks

Comment: @armani Remember that Bach in this piece is about simultaneous melodies in counterpoint, not about chords.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138049/discussion-between-aaron-and-armani).